# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am getting a null result for

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
    @synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
    @synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
    @synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
          Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription
          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
          .......

    }
```

I have one xcdatamodeld file with a entity of Person and a attribute of name.  I made a Person.h and .m file from a NSManagedObject.

Why am I getting a null result for my output.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Person''
```

Comment: assert the MOC. make sure the context isn't nil. make sure the MOM is actually what you expect too!

Comment: `assert(self.managedObjectContext);`

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", self.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName);`

Comment: Assertion failed: (self.managedObjectContext), function -[AppDelegate app is what I get after assert(self.managedObjectContext);

Comment: Show the method where you create the managedObjectContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that since I was not adding Core Data when I originally created the project, I was missing some code that is automatically generated when the core data option is ticked. Thus, when I followed some tutorials online, this automatically generated code is assumed. That's where I messed up.

Comment: I am facing the same scenario. I manually added code to use core data and now having the same issue as you did. Can you please share the tutorials that you followed?

Comment: look here if future people having issues about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076103/how-to-assign-a-managed-object-context-to-the-application-delegate-in-ios

Answer (score 12):

In your viewController.m implementation file, right under this bit of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
```

add this bit of code:

```
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the code that is running when the exception is raised is being run on the same thread that you created the managed object context on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using project template that uses NSPersistentContainer, make sure you run this on iOS 10+ or it will fail silently with initialization and crash when you perform some sort of Core Data operation.